# Regex. How to process all HTML tags in one line?

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I written PHP script which transform all inline CSS in HTML tags to classes
https://gist.github.com/iBars/aa52c6119e53908c91ac553aeba229e0

But it correctly process only that tags, which only one on the line.

[OK] `<div style="width: 50%;">123</div>`

[BROKEN RESULT] `<div style="width: 50%;">123 <span style="font-size: 24px;">456</span> 789</div>`

How to make my script process multiple tags in line?

Comment: It isn't the way to go: 1) you can't use a line by line approach with html. 2) it's from far easier to use DOMDocument and XPath to get and to edit html attributes.

Comment: The code should be here. The `.` doesn't include new lines unless the `s` modifier is used.

Comment: aside the fact that regexes are not built to parse HTML ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7393478)), how can we consistently help you if you don't show your regex?

Answer (score -1):

Solved by using regex below while replace in Notepad++

From: `>([^\r])`

To: `>\r\n$1`

This code will force all HTML opened tags move on new line. Then I running my script, getting result and use online HTML-formatter/-beautifier tool on it for removing uglification from regex above